# Creating XSSFWorkbook object gives error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I need to create excel file and write some sample data in it. I am using Apache POI for this.
I have added following jars in the build path of eclipse:

```
poi-4.1.0.jar
 poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar
```

and imported those in my code. But whenever I create object of XSSFWorkbook and try to run the code I get run time error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

I have written whole program and whenever I run it, it gives me this error.
So I just created one object and tried to run it but it is giving me the same error.

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;



public class CreateExcel {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //Blank workbook
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();


        }
}
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components -> needs `xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar`

Comment: @AxelRichter Not working though

Comment: @AxelRichter If I write sysout and print something from main it works fine. but as soon as I create Object of XSSFWorkbook  and try to run program it gives me classDefNotFoundError